# How to subtract number in previous line from current line's using grep?

Tags: command-line, grep, terminal

I use grep to get the output of `mysqladmin` as

```
sudo mysqladmin ext -i10 | grep 'buffer_pool_pages_flushed'
```

and the output is continuous (every 10 seconds) as

```
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                             | 265708726                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                             | 265735665                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                             | 265751712                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                             | 265754576                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed                             | 265774380                                        |
```

How can I adjust the `grep` command to output the differences between consecutive numbers in the second column, like

```
26939 (265735665-265708726)
16047 (265751712-265735665)
2864 (265754576-265751712)
19804 (265774380-265754576)
```

Comment: Do you mean those exact strings or the actual number that is the difference between the two? You can't do either with just `grep`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I mean the number in the second column. I only need the second column. I anticipated; as I searched I couldn't find a trick to do this with `grep`. what's your suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append:

```
| awk '{if(NR>1){print $4-last,"("$4"-"last")"} last=$4}'
```

Output:

```
26939 (265735665-265708726)
16047 (265751712-265735665)
2864 (265754576-265751712)
19804 (265774380-265754576)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/buffer_pool_pages_flushed/{curr=$(NF-1); print curr-prev; prev=curr}'
```